# How to insert data in DB (SQLite3 or sth) after parsing through casperjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new at ruby on rails and casperjs!

I wrote code that parsing a lot of words (innerHTML) from some webpages.

and I know how to run this code and I can check data in bash terminal

But I don't know how to insert this data directly in my DB (now i'm using SQLite3)

Here is my js code...(filename : application.js)

```
var words = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

    function getWords() {
        var words = document.querySelectorAll('td.subject a');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(words, function(e) {
            return e.innerHTML;
        });
    }


        casper.start('http://www.todayhumor.co.kr/board/list.php?table=bestofbest', function() {
            // search for 'casperjs' from google form
            words = this.evaluate(getWords);
        });

        for (var i=2; i <=5; i++) {
        casper.thenOpen('http://www.todayhumor.co.kr/board/list.php?table=bestofbest&page='+i, function() {
            // search for 'casperjs' from google form

            words = words.concat(this.evaluate(getWords));
        });
        }

    casper.run(function() {
        // echo results in some pretty fashion
        this.echo(words.length + ' links found:').exit();
        this.echo(words.join('\n')).exit();
});
```

and

I run this code through terminal like this!

```
username@wow:~/workspace/app/assets/javascripts $ casperjs application.js
```

and the result is *(for example)*

```
Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
150 words found:
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
word7
word8
word9
...
```

maybe the number of words is over **7,000,000**!

So I want to insert this data in my DB table(seed.rb file)

tell you more details, the db table is consist of 3 columns and will have many rows(**7,000,000** of parsing data)

here is my code of file in migrate directory and **I want to insert words that I parsed in column2(:word)!!**

```
class CreateFans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :fans do |t|
       t.string :type
       t.string :word
       t.string :spelling

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and this is codes of `seeds.rb` *(for example)*

```
my_initial_words = [
                    ['fruits', 'apple', 'ap'],
                    ['fruits', 'banana', 'ba'],
                    ['fruits', 'kiwi', 'ki'],
                    ['fruits', 'melon', 'me'],
                    ['foods', 'cake', 'ca'],
                    ['foods', 'pizza', 'pi'],
                    ['foods', 'hamburger', 'ha'],
                    ['foods', 'hotdog', 'ho'],
                    ['foods', 'toast', 'to']                        
                  ]    
my_initial_words.each do |word_data|
  Fan.create(type: word_data[0], word: word_data[1], spelling: word_data[2])
end
```

As a conclusion, I'd like to know how to insert parsing data(through casperjs) directly in my DB seed file! or are there any good way to save the data??

Thanks for read my long question!

Comment: are you getting an error?  what's preventing you from saving this data now?

Comment: You really can't if the DB doesn't provide an http api. But surely you can write your results to a file and call some other script which adds the data to the DB.

Comment: Oh, I mean.. in casperjs, I just can check result of parsing only in bash terminal and I can't write 7,000,000 of words one by one in my seeds.rb so I'd like to know how to do it...!

Comment: And additionally, I will not parse data just once, maybe I have to do 3,000 times because I have to crawl many of different web pages...